# Spring Boot Health Check - SQS Consumer

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Is there a Spring Boot Actuator Health Check endpoint for SQS? I have built a SQS consumer and I want to check if SQS is up and running. I am not using JMSlistener for connecting to SQS but rather using Spring Cloud Libraries.

I implemented the below health check endpoint. This returns the below error when I delete the queue and try to hit the health check endpoint. If there is a connectivity issue or if the SQS service goes down , will I be getting a similar error which will eventually cause the health check endpoint to fail?

> com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: The
>   specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version. (Service:
>   AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue; Request ID:
>   cd8e205d-dc43-535e-931f-7332733bd16c)

```
public class SqsQueueHealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    private final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync;
    private final String queueName;

    public SqsQueueHealthIndicator(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync, String queueName) {
        this.amazonSQSAsync = amazonSQSAsync;
        this.queueName = queueName;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) {
        try {
            amazonSQSAsync.getQueueUrl(queueName);
            builder.up();
        } catch (QueueDoesNotExistException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            builder.down(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**Beans**

```
@Bean
SqsQueueHealthIndicator queueHealthIndicator(@Autowired AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync, @Value("${sqs.queueName}") String queueName) {
    return new SqsQueueHealthIndicator(amazonSQSAsync, queueName);
}

@Bean
SqsQueueHealthIndicator deadLetterQueueHealthIndicator(@Autowired AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync, @Value("${sqs.dlQueueName}") String deadLetterQueueName) {
    return new SqsQueueHealthIndicator(amazonSQSAsync, deadLetterQueueName);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write a custom health check like below to check your queue exists or not by calling [getQueueUrl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSClient.html#getQueueUrl-java.lang.String-) using [AWS Java SDK lib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.9.0).

```
    @Component
public class SQSHealthCheck implements HealthIndicator {
    @Override
    public Health health() {
        int errorCode = check(); // perform some specific health check
        if (errorCode != 0) {
            return Health.down()
              .withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build();
        }
        return Health.up().build();
    }

    public int check() {
        /**
        your logic to check queue exists or not using by calling getQueueUrl . e.g you will get queue url of a queue named "SampleQueue" like https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/12XXX56789XXXX/SampleQueue
        **/
        return 0; // 0 or 1 based on result
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to use spring cloud libraries and want to check status based on whether sqslistener has received and processed the message or not

Comment: Sorry , I added additional info. I didn't state my question clearly. I just wanted to see if this implementation is sufficient or if I should do anything more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes.This is the correct approach that I was referring.

Regarding "QueueDoesNotExistException" , make sure you are passing the correct queue like this with proper credential. 
https://sqs.{aws zone}.amazonaws.com/{you_AWS_account}/{Queue_Name}.
You can execute the same AWS operation using AWS CLI check what parameter you are missing in this health method.