# 502 when running SQS test using localstack

Tags: java, spring, amazon-sqs, spring-test, localstack

I'm trying to run some tests with SQS using localstack. However, I keep getting a 502. This works for a co-worker, but it doesn't work on my local machine, on our pipeline, or on docker. The error is the same everywhere, so I'm sending the docker version, since it's probably easier to show what's installed.

Basically I'm creating a docker image that installs java, python, and executes the gradle build from the /repo folder, executing integration tests.

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.2-jdk-oraclelinux7

RUN ["yum", "install", "-y", "python", "python-pip"]
RUN ["pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pip"]
RUN ["pip", "install", "virtualenv"]

VOLUME ["/repo"]

ARG sourceDir

COPY ["${sourceDir}", "/repo"]
WORKDIR "/repo"

ENTRYPOINT ["/repo/gradlew", "clean", "integrationTest"]
```

My test code looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@RunWith(LocalstackTestRunner.class)
public class TimeoutQueueTest {

    private AmazonSQS client;
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "my queue";

   @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

   @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule springClassRule = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

   @Before
    public void setup() {
        Map<String, String> attributeMap = new HashMap<>();
        attributeMap.put("DelaySeconds", "0");
        attributeMap.put("MaximumMessageSize", "262144");
        attributeMap.put("MessageRetentionPeriod", "1209600");
        attributeMap.put("ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds", "20");
        attributeMap.put("VisibilityTimeout", "30");

        client = TestUtils.getClientSQS();
        CreateQueueRequest createQueueRequest = new CreateQueueRequest(QUEUE_NAME).withAttributes(attributeMap);
        //FAILS IN THE LINE BELOW!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        String standardQueueUrl = client.createQueue(createQueueRequest).getQueueUrl();

        RestAssured.port = port;
    }

(...)
}
```

It fails with:

```
 com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: null (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 502; Error Code: 502 Bad Gateway; Request ID: null)

at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1660)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1324)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1074)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2147)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2116)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2105)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeCreateQueue(AmazonSQSClient.java:756)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.createQueue(AmazonSQSClient.java:728)
at uk.co.sainsburys.giftcardservice.TimeoutQueueTest.setup(TimeoutQueueTest.java:76)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunPrepareTestInstanceCallbacks.evaluate(RunPrepareTestInstanceCallbacks.java:64)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringFailOnTimeout.evaluate(SpringFailOnTimeout.java:87)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.ProfileValueChecker.evaluate(ProfileValueChecker.java:103)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule$1.evaluate(WireMockRule.java:73)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.ProfileValueChecker.evaluate(ProfileValueChecker.java:103)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule$TestContextManagerCacheEvictor.evaluate(SpringClassRule.java:190)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cloud.localstack.LocalstackTestRunner.run(LocalstackTestRunner.java:25)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Any ideas? What am I missing? The code seems to work, since it's working for my co-worker (saw it with my own eyes). He doesn't remember having done anything different than me in terms of setup.

We're both using python 2.7.10, btw (if it matters).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this happens because your container is not ready yet by the time tests start running. You can wait for an ok healthcheck or some http path, something along the line of:

```
@ClassRule
public static final LocalStackContainer localstack = new LocalStackContainer().withServices(SQS);

@Before
public void before(){
    localstack.waitingFor(Wait.forHealthcheck()); //or Wait.forHttp("/")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try not to make assumption that AWS services are healthy at all times. In the backend of AWS services, they also have containers, where their containers can be shut down, rotated, restarted, and all their container supporting services may also be shut down, rotated or restarted. In this case, you will need a health check to ensure that sqs is ready to be pushed or listened to. The thread below may point you to how to properly listen with a health check:

[Spring Boot Health Check - SQS Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283239/spring-boot-health-check-sqs-consumer)