# Is there any way to check an external service health in a k8s microservices architecture?

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, amazon-sqs

I have a service X that consumes a message from a queue and try to post it to another service. Is there any way to check if this service is up before trying to post this message?
I've tried to get the health status by calling the `/health` endpoint (k8s), but it hasn't worked.

Comment: did you create a health check probe in deployment file ?

Comment: @TusharMahajan yes i did

Comment: did you create the same endpoint in your application as well ?

Comment: Could you provide more information? Your service consumes messages and post it to another service inside your cluster or outside? What queue software are you using?

Comment: @TusharMahajan yes.

Comment: @PjoterS it posts to another service outside the cluster. I'm using aws sqs.

Comment: Maybe this thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283239/spring-boot-health-check-sqs-consumer